# How do applications that run on iOS3 and earlier select multiple images at a time like Image Picker?

Tags: iphone, image, picker, assets

I search through the web and only find that iOS 3 and earlier versions can only use the image picker control to select the photos. Is it the only way that we can give for user to select the photo?

I know iOS4 has an asset library allowing us to access the photo but how about the earlier version? Is it not possible to get the photos from those versions?

The problem with image picker is that it only allows the user to pick one image at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can access images using the [PhotoLibrary framework](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/PhotoLibrary/PLTVOutImageTileView.h). However, since it is a private framework, Apple won't accept it.